# corresponding graphql-tag mutation of nested types in prisma

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, prisma, graphql-tag

i wonder how you can apply `mutation` using `graphql-tag` in nested types because in prisma i use `create` to assign fields

my `datamodel.graphql`

```
    type Item {
      id: ID! @id @unique
      title: String
      description: String 
      price: Int
      laptop: Laptop @relation(link: INLINE)


   }

    type Laptop {
       id: ID! @id
       brand: String

   }
```

my `schema.graphql`

```
    type Mutation {
      createItem(
        title: String
        description: String
        price: Int
        laptop: LaptopCreateOneInput
     ): Item!
    }
```

i did try this so far but it didnt work

```
    const CREATE_ITEM_MUTATION = gql`
       mutation CREATE_ITEM_MUTATION(
         $title: String!
         $description: String!
         $price: Int!
         $laptop: LaptopCreateOneInput

      ) {
        createItem(
          title: $title
          description: $description
          price: $price
          laptop:$laptop
        ) {
           id
          }
     }
   `;
```

i can apply mutation in graphql playground like this

```
    mutation {
      createItem(
        title: "computer"
        description: "some computer"
        price: 1000
        laptop: { create: { brand: "some brand" } }
     ) {
      title
     description
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

i did make it work by updating the state with `create` word

```
state = {
  title: '',
  price: 0,
  laptop: {
    create: {
      brand: ''
    }
  },
  description: '',
};
```